# Разбить numpy массив на монотонно возрастающие массивы

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, numpy

Есть такой numpy массив:

```
array([ 538,   539,   540,   542,   665,   1152,
        1205,  1243,  1258,  1506,  557,   644,
        662,   1151,  1175], dtype=int64)
```

Как его разбить на другие массивы, есть ли какие-то встроенные в numpy способы?

В массиве выше значения идут по возрастанию, как только число меньше предыдущего, то его нужно пихать в следующий массив. Можно ли это сделать с помощью numpy, не проходясь по всем числам в массиве циклом?

```
[538,  539,  540,  542,  665, 1152, 1205, 1243, 1258, 1506]
[557,  644,  662, 1151, 1175]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ 538,   539,   540,   542,   665,   1152,
              1205,  1243,  1258,  1506,  557,   644,
               662,  1151,  1175], dtype=np.int64)
```

---

Воспользуемся векторными функциями: [np.diff()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) и [np.split()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
In [26]: splitted = np.split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) < 0)[0] + 1)

In [27]: splitted
Out[27]:
[array([ 538,  539,  540,  542,  665, 1152, 1205, 1243, 1258, 1506], dtype=int64),
 array([ 557,  644,  662, 1151, 1175], dtype=int64)]
```

Пошагово:

```
In [28]: np.diff(a)
Out[28]: array([   1,    1,    2,  123,  487,   53,   38,   15,  248, -949,   87,   18,  489,   24], dtype=int64)
#              539-538, ...,     665-542, ...,                       557-1506, ...

In [29]: np.where(np.diff(a) < 0)[0]
Out[29]: array([9], dtype=int64)

In [30]: np.split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) < 0)[0] + 1)
Out[30]:
[array([ 538,  539,  540,  542,  665, 1152, 1205, 1243, 1258, 1506], dtype=int64),
 array([ 557,  644,  662, 1151, 1175], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не могли бы вы объяснить еще, как работает `np.diff`? Документация не особо помогла.

Comment: @someguy, `np.diff()` возвращает вектор (1D матрицу) в котором каждый элемент равен разнице: следующий элемент (`a[n+1]`) минус текущий элемент (`a[n]`) для 1D массивов

Answer (score 0):

как вариант:

```
 def getGrops(arr):
     arr = np.array(arr, np.float64)
     _arr = np.roll(arr,1)
     _arr[0] = np.inf
     grp = np.arange(_arr.shape[-1])[arr<_arr]
     _arr = np.roll(grp,-1).tolist()
     _arr[-1] = None
     grp = [ slice(i,l) for i,l in zip(grp, _arr) ]
     return grp
 a = np.array([ 538,   539,   540,   542,   665,   1152, 1205,  1243,  1258,  1506,  557,   644, 662,   1151,  1175], dtype=np.int64)
 grp = getGrops(a)
 for g in grp:
     print(a[g])
```

результат:

```
 [ 538  539  540  542  665 1152 1205 1243 1258 1506]
 [ 557  644  662 1151 1175]
```